# Fit a line with groupby in a pandas time series and get the slope

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo_so = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                      'time': [3.0, 4.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0],
                      'y': [4.3809523809523805, 3.5238095238095233, 5.619047619047618, 7.761904761904762, 12.476190476190476, 13.380952380952381, 17.142857142857142, 19.238095238095237, 18.285714285714285, 16.80952380952381, 18.476190476190478, 20.571428571428573, 20.33333333333334, 18.71428571428572, 18.0952380952381, 20.95238095238096, 22.285714285714292, 20.47619047619048]})
```

where each `id` is a time series.

I would like to fit a line for every `id` and get the slope.

How could I do that ?

**UPDATE**

So I can do something like:

```
import numpy as np

foo_so_f = foo_so.query('person_id == "a"')
x = np.arange(foo_so_f['time'].size)
fit = np.polyfit(x, foo_so_f['y'], deg=1)
print ("Slope : " + str(fit[0]))
```

But I want to do that for all `id`s simultaneously

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a range as x in your fit? Shouldn't `time` be more appropriate? Anyway, check if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561074/16343464) is what you want, if not please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
(foo_so.groupby('id')
       .apply(lambda x: 'Slope: %.3f' % np.polyfit(np.arange(len(x)),
                                                   x['y'],
                                                   deg=1)[0])
)
```

output:

```
id
a    Slope: 2.190
b    Slope: 0.410
```

Actually, if this is a time series, it makes probably more sense to use time as x:

```
(foo_so.groupby('id')
       .apply(lambda x: 'Slope: %.3f' % np.polyfit(x['time'],
                                                   x['y'],
                                                   deg=1)[0])
)
```

output:

```
id
a    Slope: 0.654
b    Slope: 0.410
dtype: object
```

And if you only want to print:

```
for name, group in foo_so.groupby('id'):
    print(f'Slope for {name}: %.3f' %
          np.polyfit(np.arange(len(group)),group['y'], deg=1)[0]
          )
```

output:

```
Slope for a: 2.190
Slope for b: 0.410
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the p-values also from this ?

Comment: Sure, you can use [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) instead of `numpy.polyfit`. It returns many parameters of the fit, including the `pvalue`. Let me know if you need help with it